# Regex. Camel case to underscore. Ignore first occurrence

Tags: c#, regex

For example:

```
thisIsMySample
```

should be:

```
this_Is_My_Sample
```

My code:

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(input, "([A-Z])", "_$0", System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

It works fine, but if the input is changed to:

```
ThisIsMySample
```

the output will be:

```
_This_Is_My_Sample
```

How can first occurrence be ignored?

Comment: Non Regex:    `string result = string.Concat(input.Select((x,i) => i > 0 && char.IsUpper(x) ? "_" + x.ToString() : x.ToString()));`

Comment: @sa_ddam213 - post it as an answer please - it can be upvoted than

Comment: @sa_ddam213 - which one is faster? Regex or C# pure?

Comment: not sure, that's why I left it as a comment :)

Comment: wow, I did a test 1,000,000 iterations Regex vs C# , Regex: 2569ms, C#: 1489ms

Comment: cool! which string have you used? "thisIsMySample"?

Comment: yes, added to my answer, I tried with larger strings and it still seems twice as fast

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Non-Regex solution

```
string result = string.Concat(input.Select((x,i) => i > 0 && char.IsUpper(x) ? "_" + x.ToString() : x.ToString()));
```

Seems to be quite fast too: Regex: 2569ms, C#: 1489ms

```
Stopwatch stp = new Stopwatch();
stp.Start();
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
{
    string input = "ThisIsMySample";
    string result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(input, "(?<=.)([A-Z])", "_$0",
            System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.Compiled);
}
stp.Stop();
MessageBox.Show(stp.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
// Result 2569ms

Stopwatch stp2 = new Stopwatch();
stp2.Start();
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
{
    string input = "ThisIsMySample";
    string result = string.Concat(input.Select((x, j) => j > 0 && char.IsUpper(x) ? "_" + x.ToString() : x.ToString()));
}
stp2.Stop();
MessageBox.Show(stp2.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
// Result: 1489ms
```

Comment: Good one! )) and without any Regex

Comment: Although still faster, moving the Regex to a static, eg. private static readonly Regex CompiledRegEx = new Regex("(?<=.)([A-Z])", RegexOptions.Compiled);,  reduces the execution by 300ms. Your solution, however, is still the fastest :-)

Answer (score 15):

You can use a [lookbehind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx#grouping_constructs) to ensure that each match is preceded by at least one character:

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(input, "(?<=.)([A-Z])", "_$0",
                      System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

lookaheads and lookbehinds allow you to make assertions about the text *surrounding* a match without including that text within the match.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe like;

```
var str = Regex.Replace(input, "([A-Z])", "_$0", RegexOptions.Compiled);
if(str.StartsWith("_"))
   str = str.SubString(1);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer - its seems work! +1 Try also other variations.

Comment: could also use `.TrimStart('_')`

Comment: @sa_ddam213 '_' is a smile )))

Answer (score 3):

```
// (Preceded by a lowercase character or digit) (a capital) => The character prefixed with an underscore
var result = Regex.Replace(input, "(?<=[a-z0-9])[A-Z]", m => "_" + m.Value);
result = result.ToLowerInvariant();
```

- This works for both `PascalCase` and `camelCase`.
- It creates no leading or trailing underscores.
- It leaves in tact any sequences of non-word characters and underscores in the string, because they would seem intentional, e.g. `__HiThere_Guys` becomes `__hi_there_guys`.
- Digit suffixes are (intentionally) considered part of the word, e.g. `NewVersion3` becomes `new_version3`.
- Digit prefixes follow the original casing, e.g. `3VersionsHere` becomes `3_versions_here`, but `3rdVersion` becomes `3rd_version`.
- Unfortunately, capitalized two-letter acronyms (e.g. in `IDNumber`, where `ID` would be considered a separate word), as suggested in [Microsoft's Capitalization Conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043(v=vs.100).aspx), are not supported, since they conflict with other cases. I recommend, in general, to resist this guideline, as it is a seemingly arbitrary exception to the convention of *not* capitalizing acronyms. Stick with `IdNumber`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to modify your regex to not match the first char by defining you want to ignore the first char at all by

```
.([A-Z])
```

The above regex simply excludes every char that comes first and since it is not in the braces it would be in the matching group.

Now you need to match the second group like Bibhu noted:

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(s, "(.)([A-Z])", "$1_$2", System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

Comment: thanks for response! ) Doesnt work cause not only first letter is replaced with it.

Comment: Sorry mate, I did an edit. That's what you want :) One regex to fit them all :)

Answer (score 2):

Elaborating on sa_ddam213's solution, mine extends this:

```
public static string GetConstStyleName(this string value)
        {
            return string.Concat(value.Select((x, i) =>
            {
                //want to avoid putting underscores between pairs of upper-cases or pairs of numbers, or adding redundant underscores if they already exist.
                bool isPrevCharLower = (i == 0) ? false : char.IsLower(value[i - 1]);
                bool isPrevCharNumber = (i == 0) ? false : char.IsNumber(value[i - 1]);
                return (isPrevCharLower && (char.IsUpper(x) || char.IsNumber(x))) //lower-case followed by upper-case or number needs underscore
                    || (isPrevCharNumber && (char.IsUpper(x))) //number followed by upper-case needs underscore
                    ? "_" + x.ToString() : x.ToString();
            })).ToUpperInvariant();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `".([A-Z])"` for your regular expression, and then `"_$1"` for the replacement. So you use the captured string for the replacement and with the leading `.` you are sure you are not catching the first char of your string.

Comment: Thanks for your post! ) It doenst work - cause also other letter will be replaced with it

Comment: you mena 2 Replaces - like this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/18781117/502950 - but you were almost in the same time - upvote too )